# Excel: Find and Replace - Adjacent Columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, find, find-and-replace

In excel, after I search and click "find all", I want to see the matching adjacent column values in the results list (so I can compare them).

Is there a way for me to archive something like this?
Or perhaps a software that does this?

Thanks!

Comment: Highlight duplicates and then sort ascending. No need to find.

Comment: I like to use the VLOOKUP function.  If the result returns #N/A then I know there is no match.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use *Search*, consider using *AutoFilter*  to "find" relevant data.  That way the entire row is visible and you can easily see any adjacent column.